# Number of ajax call increases every time submission of the form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using below code to submit my form using ajax.

**First : For the first time, ajax doesn't call, and then i have to click it again. After the second click, then ajax is called..**

Second : every time i submit, number of ajax call increases.

for example, if i submit it for the first time, it will be called once.
then, if i click it on second time, it calls it two time. and so on 3 time, it calls it three time......

Below is my code. Please help me out here.. I am beginner at jQuery.

i have used bootstrap validate on form submission.

```js
$("#subscriptionform").validate(
  {
    rules: 
    {
      subemail: 
      {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) 
    {//alert("dfd");
      $('#subscribeBtn').on('click', function () {
         var $btn = $(this);
        $btn.button('loading');
        //alert("dfadsfs");        
        
        
          $.ajax({
            type: $(form).attr('method'),
            url: BASEURL+"contactus/subscribe",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function (status) 
              {
                $('#subinputid').val('');
                if(status==1)
                {
                  alert("You have subscribed successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                  alert("You have alerady subscribed.");
                }
                console.log(status);
                //alert(status);
                return false;
              } 
          });
        setTimeout(function () {
                $btn.button('reset');
            }, 1000);
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<form method="post" id="subscriptionform" name="subscriptionform" action="<?= BASEURL.'contactus/subscribe' ?>">
             <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 padding0 text-right">
               <div class="newsletter-label">
                NEWSLETTER
               </div>
               <div>
                <input class="email-input" id="subinputid" name="subemail" type="text" placeholder="ENTER YOUR EMAIL" >
               </div>
             </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 padding0">
                <button id="subscribeBtn" data-loading-text="Subscribing..." autocomplete="off" class="btn-subscrib" type="submit" name="subscribe" value="SUBSCRIBE">SUBSCRIBE</button>
              </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: That is because you are binding the AJAX call to the subscription button, but you create a new click event trigger whenever a validation attempt is made. Therefore, with increasing number of validations (triggered by form submission), you have more and more click handlers being bound to the button, causing duplication of the AJAX call.

Comment: So now, should i separate the click function from the ajax call right?

Comment: You might want to change your logic. Your current logic is validate form -> if valid, bind click handler. What about, bind validation to click handler, and then if valid just submit the form? (i.e. the other way round)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put unbind before the line as below:

```
$('#subscribeBtn').unbind('click');
$('#subscribeBtn').on('click', function () {
     var $btn = $(this);
```

will work this fine here, why this happens when call validate, the click is binding again and again, so unbind the click event and again bind the event.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working now :)

Ajax recall is not happening now.

but As i Described, For the first time, The Button is unclickable. 

could you plz help me with that,,,

I am tired of finding the solution for that.

Comment: exactly what u are facing now? first time click is working and then button is not enabled?

Comment: No, For the first time, ajax doesn't call, and then i have to click it again.
After the second click, then ajax is called.

Comment: did u fix it?why the setTimeout function? can u comment that and try?

Comment: No, i am still stuck there in that problem.
That timeout is for ajax call competition. if i comment it then loading goes continue and in order to make that button work again, i have to reload the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64924/discussion-between-pulkit-pithva-and-ashique-c-m).